# Autohotkey check file checksum

Tags: autohotkey, checksum

I need an AHK script which will check/compare an MD5 checksum value for a specified file.

Something like this:

---

'Does file "`%userprofile%\appsettings\app.ini`" have an MD5 checksum value `A465564D654E56464025456F`?

- if YES
  `Msgbox "not changed"`
- if NO
  `filedelete, "%userprofile%\appsettings\app.ini"`

  - Then:
    `filecopy, "%userprofile%\appsettings\app.kackup", "%userprofile%\appsettings\app.ini"`

Exit script

---

I need this to be run manually - on demand, not a persistent script.

I prefer it to be an Autohotkey script, but if it is too complicated, powershell or batch script is fine too.

Thank you

Comment: Would you mind telling us what you plan on using this for?

Comment: It's for a custom made buggy application which sometimes messes up with its configuration file causing the app not functional on next run. So I'd like a script which will check if the config file is intact and if not, it will replace the corrupted file a good one. I don't want to replace the file everytime the app starts for performance reasons (the good config file solves the problem but the application is reset to default settings). The app developer left the project and currently there's no one willing to fix it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution:

```
var:= ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell").Exec("cmd.exe /q /c CertUtil -hashfile %userprofile%/appsettings/app.ini MD5").StdOut.ReadAll()
outputArr := (StrSplit(var , "`r`n"))
out:=outputArr[2]
;MsgBox %out%

if(out=="A465564D654E56464025456F"){
    Msgbox not changed
    ExitApp
}
else{
    MsgBox Different MD5- restoring...
    filecopy, %userprofile%\appsettings\app.backup, %userprofile%\appsettings\app.ini, 1
    ExitApp
}
```

See the full explanation of the MD5 hashing part [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67420209/how-to-find-the-md5-hash-of-a-file). In summary:

> We can use the Windows CertUtil tool to find the MD5 hash sum and
> Parse the output by StrSpliting it into different lines (The MD5 sum
> itself will be on the second line).

The rest of the script is just some logic to check if the hash is the same as the one given (`A465564D654E56464025456F`), and if it is not, [`filecopy`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileCopy.htm) the `.backup`<sup>**1**</sup> onto the `.ini` file. Note that we do not need to explicitly call [`filedelete`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileDelete.htm) if we give [`filecopy`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileCopy.htm) the ability to overwrite files.

---

<sup>**1**</sup>- I think that you might have meant a `.backup` file instead of a `.kackup` file, but I may be wrong. If you wanted a `.kackup` file, replace `app.backup` with `app.kackup` in the script.

Comment: Thank you very much! I mean thanks a million! This is exactly what I needed! It works like charm!!! (And yes, that ".kackup" was a typo, it supposed to be ".backup".